# about getting values from Tlist in delphi

Tags: delphi, tlist

I am storing pixel values into a file. From that file I am reading into `Tlist` but I am getting following error:

> incompatible type : sortstring to string

and

> incompatible type : string to pointer

What could cause this?

Code:

```
segment_point, first_line_point, end_line_point: TPoint;
x1, y1, x2, y2, Px, Py: Integer;

segment_point := TempList.Items[y];
first_line_point := myList.Items[y];
end_line_point := myList.Items[y + 1];
x1 := first_line_point.x;
y1 := first_line_point.y;
x2 := end_line_point.x;
y2 := end_line_point.y;
Px := segment_point.x;
Py := segment_point.y;
```

Comment: It would help if you would post the code you are trying to do this with.

Comment: `TList` holds pointers and is a legacy class. You should be using a generic container, e.g. `TList<T>`.

Comment: I think you should start with showing how you are writing to the file. Sofar you only mentioned 'pixel values', while it appears that you also write (or think you do) x- and y- coordinates. So please show your file writing method.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is very simple as mentioned before.

"segment_point" is defined as TPoint.

"Templist.items" is of type Pointer (see Delphi help or hover with the mouse over your code). Which is very different!!!. 
So you can't assign different types. The missing code should show us how you deal with "TList".

When you do it as expected you can use a cast to access your data like: TPoint(TempList.items[y]).

But please follow the hints before and inform yourself about generic container!!

Comment: No. `TPoint` is a record. You cannot cast a pointer to `TPoint`, or indeed vice versa.

Comment: upps, you are right. So you have to define a class.

Comment: Not necessarily. You can `TList<TPoint>`.

Comment: @ChristineRoss - you should fix your answers when they are wrong.